# What are the pros/cons of this strategy

Tags: altcoin, investing

I would like to buy 10 crypto currencies ($100~$150) each and leave it for a long period.
What are the pros/cons of such approach?
Some things I can think of

- Coins disappear with time and some might be erased over time...?
- Holding them?
- Creating a paper wallet for each (I do not want it to be in an exchange, I do not trust them)?
- Transaction fees might be too high?

I don't know what I don't know, so I am not sure what to be careful of, so I am asking from your experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you buy those coins under a BTC base and when they are very low price would be better.

But considering BTC is growing fast every year, I would just keep my holdings in BTC. Much safer.